# Brooks' theorem in the infinite

Tags: graph-theory, coloring, infinite-graphs

Let $G=(V;E)$ be an infinite graph, with $|V|$ an uncountable cardinal. Suppose that the maximum degree of any $v \in V$ is $\kappa$, where $\kappa \leq |V|$ is an infinite cardinal. Does it follow that the chromatic number of $G$ is at most $\kappa$?

In other words, does Brooks' theorem adapt to infinite graphs?

Comment: If each vertex has degree at most $\kappa$ (an infinite cardinal) then each connected component has at most $\kappa$ vertices (assuming the axiom of choice of course) whence the chromatic number is at most $\kappa$. This is much less interesting than Brooks' theorem.

Comment: How can this be? If each connected component has at most $\kappa$ vertices, and $|V| > \kappa$, then why should there not be a way to connect these components by adding only one edge between pairs of components, thus preserving the cardinality of the degrees of the vertices?

Comment: The problem is that if two vertices are connected by a path, that path must be finite. The set of finite paths from a vertex $v$ has cardinality $|\kappa^{<\infty}| = |\kappa|$. (And in response to your suggested strategy: the way you'd usually pick a spanning tree stops working for uncountably many components. And if you try to add even just one edge between **every** pair of components, you'll exceed the degree bound at some vertex.)

Comment: The most interesting infinite version of Brooks' theorem I know is for effectively $\Delta$-coloring (that is, having an algorithm that, for each vertex, eventually tells you its color) a countably infinite graph with finite maximum degree $\Delta$.

Comment: Do you have a reference for this theorem? You have both been very helpful!

Comment: I found it mentioned in [Brooks' theorem and beyond](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/epdf/10.1002/jgt.21847) by Cranston and Rabern, but for the actual proof you want either Tverberg's [On Schmerl's effective version of Brooks' theorem](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/82073073.pdf), which builds on [the original paper by Schmerl](https://doi.org/10.4153/CJM-1982-075-6).